# How to make DNS Lookup with Python except dnspython

Tags: python, dns, lookup

The dnspython is powerful, but for simple case just need to get the IP from domain(like google.com -> 46.82.174.69), it is a little complicated. Any other simple and straightforward way?

Answer (score 2):

```
import socket

addr = socket.gethostbyname('google.com')

print(addr)
```

The output

```
46.82.174.69
```